# Compiling a C project along with two libraries

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am working on a C project for Linux-environment (compiled with gcc). I am using two libraries:

- [SDL image](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release-1.2.html) (source is stored at the directory `SDL_img`).
- [SDL TTF](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release-1.2.html) (source is stored at the directory `SDL_ttf`).

My `CFLAGS` variable:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall -g -lm `sdl-config --cflags` -ISDL_img -ISDL_ttf
```

As you can see, I am including those two library-directories.

My gcc command include the following:

```
`sdl-config --libs` -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_img -lSDL_ttf
```

Finally, in my project I have the following includes:

```
#include "SDL_ttf.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
```

For some reason, I get errors of the type:

`undefined reference to 'IMG_Load'`

Why?

### **EDIT:**

```
all: Chess.o Commons.o Console.o Controls.o Coords.o File.o GameState.o GUI.o Keyboard.o List.o Minimax.o Move.o Piece.o SettingsState.o Slots.o Square.o Str.o
    gcc  $^ -lm -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -g -o Chess `sdl-config --libs` -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_img -lSDL_ttf
```

Comment: Show the full compilation command in the makefile and that gets run and the full error context.

Comment: Edited. As for the the full error context, I don't think it's needed - just bunch of `undefined reference` errors (and some other irrelevant errors)

Comment: @hibyte, you might be right that the error context would not be helpful, but it does not serve you well to deny the information requests of people who are offering to help you.  If you could be confident what messages are and are not relevant then you probably would not need to pose the question.

Comment: Where does the `SDL_Img` library (that presumably contains the `IMD_Load` symbol) live?

Comment: Myself, I would be looking among the error messages for one that complained about being unable to find `libSDL_img`.  Not only would that readily explain the problem, but in my environment, the library you appear to want is spelled `libSDL_image` (which does not have any necessary relationship with the name of any directory related to that libnrary).

Comment: @EtanReisner, they're live at `src/SDL_ttf` and `src/SDL_img`.

Comment: the `makefile` also lives at this directory.

Comment: Okay, I was misleading before; no executable created for SDL_ttf, SDL_img

Comment: So how do I compile those libraries?

Comment: Does `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl SDL_image` work?

Comment: what does `sdl-config --libs` and `sdl-config --cflags` says? in my system it give me the Ipath and Lpath where are those includes and libraries, if you have your SDL sources in src/SDL_xxx then the -Ipath in your cflags should point somewhere to src/SDL_xxx/include and the -Lpath should point to path where are your .so or .a library, which you first has to build from those src/SDL_xxx sources

Comment: in your project root dir (where you have the src dir) execute this:
find . -iname "*.a" -o -iname "*.so"
that will give you where are yours builded libs and that path is what you have to get after the -L option

Comment: The built libraries are under `src/SDL_ttf` and `src/SDL_img`? Are those added to the link command with `-L` anywhere?

Comment: I assume that you have installed SDL with package manager and then downloaded SDL_image and SDL_ttf by hand, if this is the case then you have to first build those and then do what I wrote

Comment: Well, SDL library installed on my machine, but I'm not able to install (using a package-manager) those two libraries (SDL_TTF, SDL_image). Instead, I am expected to compile it myself from source as part of the project-makefile.

Comment: `sdl-config --libs` results `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL` and `sdl-config --cflags` results `-I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT`

Answer (score 0):

Just `cd` to those src/SDL_xxx dirs and do `make` to build those libraries and then set the correct -L and -I. It failed on linking so the -I is "good" but your path to your libraries is incorect

basically linker is now searching its paths to find libSDL_img  and libSDL_ttf then it also searches /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and it still can not find it, that is why you are getting undefined referecne.

To fix this: first build those SDL_xxx and then search where are those libraries and pass somethig like this along with other to gcc:

```
-Lsrc/SDL_img/lib -lSDL_img  -Lsrc/SDL_ttf/lib -lSDL_ttf
```

Comment: there's is no `makefile` in those libraries. There are `makefile.in` and `makefile.am` though.

Comment: And can it be done automatically from the `makefile`?

Comment: I've read the script `configure` should be executed first, but I don't have the permission to do so. Is there a workaround?

Comment: yes configure should be used first, why don't you have permissions?

if you do ls -al in those directory what user is there? did you downloaded those files under root and do this under normal user? if this is the case then you can sudo chown user:group -R dir to have permisions